# Django Form initial dict always empty

Tags: python, django

**views.py**

```
class PlayerListView(PlayerViewMixin, FormMixin, ListView):
    form_class = PlayerFilterForm(initial={'min_rating': 1})
    paginate_by = 50
    template_name = 'players/player_list.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PlayerListView, self).get_context_data()
        context['form'] = self.form_class
        # context['form'].fields['maxrating'].initial = self.request.GET.get('maxrating')
        print(self.get_initial())
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super(PlayerListView, self).get_queryset()
        minrating = self.request.GET.get('minrating')
        maxrating = self.request.GET.get('maxrating')

        if self.request.GET.get('minrating'):
            qs = qs.filter(overall_rating__gte=minrating)

        if self.request.GET.get('maxrating'):
            qs = qs.filter(overall_rating__lte=maxrating)

        return qs
```

**forms.py**

```
class PlayerFilterForm(forms.Form):
    min_rating = forms.ChoiceField(
        initial=1,
        choices=[
            (x, x) for x in range(1, 100)
        ]
    )

...
```

The code is messy, just playing around at the moment. I need to work in a way to do dynamic initial data which i can do in `get_initial` but regardless of whatever i do my initial dict is always empty. Am i missing something really dumb here?

Comment: Have you actually defined the `get_initial` method? What does it look like?

Comment: @DanielRoseman i haven't set it. It's just been left as is in the CBV by default (http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.7/django.views.generic.edit/FormMixin/)

Comment: Er, so how are you expecting it to provide dynamic data?

Comment: @DanielRoseman It's not yet, i haven't got that far as at the moment the initial is always empty. When i can get it to display the 1 i'm defining at the moment i would move on to the dynamic data

Comment: Well I'm not sure why you expect that 1 to appear in the dictionary returned from get_initial. As you say, get_initial is for dynamic form initial data: that's quite a separate thing from a field's initial constant.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Yea speaking to a guy i work with i noticed how stupid i was being. It was working the whole time but when i'm trying to set the new initial (1) to be the same as the default initial (1) i'm not going to see anything on the front end. When i change it to say 47 it obviously works.. Just some late night sheer blindness, my bad!